# Express checkout PayPal, guest mode does not always working

Tags: php, paypal, woocommerce, express-checkout

I am trying to use Express checkout in Pay Pal Api.
And I want to use it in guest mode (without creating of account), everything of it work through WooCommerce.
For all of that i done:

- SET "PayPal Account Optional: On."
- SET  LANDINGPAGE=Billing
- SET SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole
- Settings in wooCommerce also correct

And yes I have business account.
I cleaned cache and once time it even worked but after few time testing its broken again and I do not know what to do.
I tested in different browsers even IPs, one time some magic it used to work but failed again. 
So maybe someone know how to make it work constantly?

Comment: Are you sending any LOCALECODE with the SEC request?  Are you using [PayPal for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/) by chance?

Comment: Yes, I am using exectly that plugin, about LOCALCODE I am not sure.

Comment: Ok, in the Express Checkout settings look for the option "Use WordPress Locale Code".  Disable that option and you should see a more consistent flow.

Comment: ok, I tryied to set up LOCALCODE to US, and it start to work but mostly client would be from Ukraine, so when they going to change country (and they should do this) PayPal block guest checkout and force account creating.
And if I set up UA or RU or GE  its not working.

Comment: That's correct.  Guest checkout is only available to payers in certain countries.  Unfortunately, there's no way around that.

Answer (score 0):

- Verified PayPal account
- Confirmed email address
- Guest Checkout enabled
- With Express Checkout their cart must pass "SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole"

If all of these are met and it's not available then our system has decided to disable the guest checkout option for risk reasons. This is not a permanent decision and it will be available in the future. If you are a big merchant and has a good TPV, you can check with your account manager/business support to help you with this.

If you want to make sure that you want to use Guest checkout, you will need to go for Payflow or PayPal Payments PRO (depending on merchant country).

Comment: I can not use Pro because its work only in US, CA, UK and my account is in Germany. So did I understand right you want to said that guest checkout works randomly ? :)